# Custom Calender Adapted for 2 Week timetable

Tags: java, android, calendar

I am trying to create an android app that creates a permanent notification of the days lessons for college that changes daily. However I have a two week timetable, how would I program this so that the app knows which of the two weeks, A and B, it is and the day?

Comment: You should use WeekView. Go through it : https://github.com/alamkanak/Android-Week-View